# Extract closest matches from a list

Tags: excel

I would like to be able to extract the next smallest and largest matches from a list of standard items so for example if someone were to enter  900 x 1000 x 60 FF I would like to extract the closest standard items we have from this list.

[Standard Item List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyQ4P.png)

Comment: Have a search on here, there are a couple of q that look at that.

Answer (score 0):

So, have a look at the two options shown here:

[image]

Check match() as you can go low or high using the 3rd argument.